# If Grid has particular value & Highlight it on form load

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, datagridview

I have a string & datagridview. On form load, if grid has that string in 1st column (in any row) i would like that grid to Highlight the particular cell.

I tried it by (hard coding) using `dataGridView1.SelectedRows[1].Cells[1].Selected = true;` just to check if it highlights or not.

But it say "index out of range"

**UPDATE:**

String i have is MANAGER4 & if Grid has value MANAGER4 in its column & i want to show  it as `selctedcell`.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it worked for me.

```
  for (int x = 0; x < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; x++)
   {
        if (dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[0].Value.ToString() == yourString)
        {
             dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[0].Selected = true;

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Considering that you are talking about *first* column, why do you want to access cell using index 1?

Access it using 0.

And you can also use`SelectedRows` collection, probably if there is no any row selected.

To work with coloring of DataGrid cells you need to work with [Cell Styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1yef90x0.aspx)

**EDIT**

Something like this you can have in some function:

```
for (int x = 0; x < grid.Rows.Count; x++)
{

  if (..condition..)
  {
    //Red color set on the cell
    grid.Rows[x].Cells[0].Style.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for could be done by handling the `CellFormatting` event of the grid.

Within it just check the particular cell (corresponding to your column) and then you can set the background color as desired. This would show the cell in Red Color (which i assume is what you want)

```
void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)
    {
       //check condition and assign color
       e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;                    
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should set `FullRowSelect` property of the `DataGridView` to `false`, in order to be able to select a single cell. After that you can easily select the desired cell like this: `datagridView1.Rows[rowInd].Cells[colInd].Selected = true`, where `rowInd` and `colInd` are the indexes of the row and the column respectively (you should remember, that indexes start from 0).

You got `IndexOutOfRange` exception, because you tried to access `SelectedRows` collection of the `DataGridView` when no rows were selected yet.